# What determines the order in which predicates are run?

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic

I am working with some code that was in part written by my professor that takes a tableau as input, expands it, and then outputs the complete tableau.

I am having trouble understanding the logic behind the order in which the predicates are being run. What is the deciding factor that would, say, make the program address conjunction before negation if both were present in the original formula? And how does recursion play into this?

The code is as follows:

```
%negation
expand([[not(not(X))|B]|T], T1) :-
    expand([[X|B]|T], T1).

%conjunction
expand([[(X)+(Y)|B]|T], T1):-
    expand([[X, Y|B]|T], T1).

expand([[not((X)+(Y))|B]|T], T1):-
    expand([[not(X)|B], [not(Y)|B]|T], T1).

%disjunction
expand([[(X)/(Y)|B]|T], T1):-
    expand([[X|B], [Y|B]|T], T1).

expand([[not((X)/(Y))|B]|T], T1):-
    expand([[not(X), not(Y)|B]|T], T1).

%not sure what the rest is or how it works
expand([[X|B]|T1], T5) :-
    expand([B], T2), distribute(X,T2,T3), expand(T1,T4), append(T3,T4,T5).

expand([[]|T1], [[]|T2]) :-
    expand(T1, T2).

expand([],[]).

distribute(X,[B|T],[[X|B]|T1]) :-
        distribute(X,T,T1).

distribute(_,[],[]).
```

Apologies for the vague post, I am unfamiliar with this language

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to "teach me Prolog from scratch"? That seems too big for a stackoverflow answer and there are books written to do that. e.g. [Learn Prolog Now, free online edition](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pageid=online) - chapter 2 is unification and proof search, that explains "what determines the order they are run". Chapter 3 is recursion. You will also need chapter 4 on Lists and recursing down lists to make sense of the predicate header syntax, and chapter 1, Prolog Syntax, to make sense of the "complex terms" in the lists in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

A Prolog program consists of

- *Facts*, a simple statement of truth. Something like this

  ```
  mother( jane , alice ) .
  mother( jane , john  ) .
  ```

  is two *facts* that state that Jane is the mother of both Alice and John.
- *Predicates*, more complex assertions of truth. Something like this:

  ```
  sibling(X,Y) :- same_mother(X,Y), same_father(X,Y) .

  half_sibling(X,Y) :-    same_mother(X,Y) , \+ same_father(X,Y) .
  half_sibling(X,Y) :- \+ same_mother(X,Y) ,    same_father(X,Y) .

  same_mother(X,Y) :- mother(M,X), mother(M,Y) .

  same_father(X,Y) :- father(F,X), father(F,Y) .
  ```

  states that

  - two people, X and Y, are siblings if they have both the same mother and the same father, and
  - two people, X and Y, are half-siblings if they have either

    - the same mother and different fathers, or
    - different mothers and the same father

Each predicate is a *logic proposition* written in a restricted form of the *predicate calculus*, and forms what amounts to a search tree (more of a search *graph*, really). When you query/execute a predicate, say

```
sibling(stephen,alice).
```

Prolog's *inference engine* essentially traverses the search tree until either *succeeds* or *fails*. If it succeeded, one can backtrack into it, and it will continue the traversal until it either succeeds again, or fails.

So, the order in which predicates are "executed" is entirely dependent on the predicate with which evaluation began, and it's structure.

Note that, depending on what arguments/parameters are instantiated or not instantiated, when a predicate is evaluated, allows one to ask questions with more than one answer:

- `sibling( john, X ).` asks the question "Who are John's siblings?"
- `sibling( X , Y ).` asks the question "Who are all the pairs of siblings?"

A good text to start learning Prolog are

- Clocksin+Mellish's [*Programming in Prolog*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540006788) — it's a pretty good introduction to the language.
- Clocksin's [*Clause and Effect*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540629718) — I've heard good things about this as a beginner's text, but I've not read it.

Once you've gotten the basics down...

- Sterling+Shapiro's [*The Art of Prolog*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262193388) is a most excellent book to take you deeper

And O'Keefe's [*The Craft of Prolog*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262512270) is yet a deeper dive.